# list of class with members from derived class

Tags: vb.net

I'd like to create list of class of different devices with its designed members. It this possible?

```
Public lstDevices As New List(Of Device)

    Public Class Device
        Public strName As String
        Public iKind As Integer 
    End Class
```

Then I'll have particular kind of Device named Printer

```
    Public Class Printer : Inherits Device
        public shared  iAge as integer
    End Class
```

How can I reach for ex.

```
lstDevices.Find(Function(p) p.strName = strName).iAge = 10
```

if I make `clsPrinter = new Printer()`
I can reach `clsPrinter.iAge`

But with list, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lstDevices`-list stores `Devices`, so the parent class of `Printer` which has the `iAge` property. You have to cast it appropriately. But you also have to store the result of [`List.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx) in a variable:

```
Dim foundDevice As Device = lstDevices.Find(Function(p) p.strName = strName)
If foundDevice IsNot Nothing AndAlso TypeOf foundDevice Is Printer Then
    Dim foundPrinter As Printer = DirectCast(foundDevice, Printer)
    foundPrinter.iAge = 10
End If
```

Another nice LINQ approach is:

```
Dim foundPrinters = From p In lstDevices.OfType(Of Printer)()
                    Where p.strName = strName
Dim firstPrinter As Printer = foundPrinters.FirstOrdefault()
```

Comment: Right, thanks. But I need to create new one found device? is there a way to reach out without creating of? Dim tmpDevice As Printer = CType(lstDevices.Find(Function(p) p.strName = strName), Printer)

Comment: @kwestia: i don't understand, i don't create anything. Of course you could also use your one-liner. But the only difference is that it throws an exception if the device is not a printer or no device was found. You could use `TryCast` instead. But i'd prefer the second LINQ approach.

Comment: Right, it's not new variable foundDevice but cast :) I mean to reach the device directly from the list like lstDevices.Find(Function(p) p.strName = strName).iAge =10. But anyway your solution works, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I just want to remind you that iAge property of Printer class is a **shared property**.

I prefer the LINQ methods over LINQ queries. So I tried converting Tim's query to LINQ method (minus the where criteria). I intentionally use First() instead of FirstOrDefault(). Code looks like this:

```
Module Module1

    Public lstDevices As New List(Of Device)

    Sub Main()

        lstDevices.Add(New Printer() With {.strName = "Epson", .iKind = 1})
        lstDevices.Add(New Printer() With {.strName = "HP", .iKind = 2})

        lstDevices.OfType(Of Printer).First().iAge = 10
        Console.WriteLine(lstDevices.OfType(Of Printer).First().iAge)

        Console.ReadKey(True)

    End Sub

End Module

Public Class Device
    Public strName As String
    Public iKind As Integer
End Class

Public Class Printer : Inherits Device
    Public Shared iAge As Integer
End Class
```

VS shows warnings in these lines:

```
lstDevices.OfType(Of Printer).First().iAge = 10
Console.WriteLine(lstDevices.OfType(Of Printer).First().iAge)
```

The warning for both lines is:

> Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type
>   through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated.

It means that the expression won't be evaluated because iAge is a shared property. Even if I remove the 2 lines where I add Printer instances to the list, the code **won't throw any exception**. That's because iAge property is tied to the Printer class, not instance of Printer class.

```
Sub Main()

    'lstDevices.Add(New Printer() With {.strName = "Epson", .iKind = 1})
    'lstDevices.Add(New Printer() With {.strName = "HP", .iKind = 2})

    ' these 2 lines won't throw any exceptions eventhough the list is empty
    lstDevices.OfType(Of Printer).First().iAge = 10
    Console.WriteLine(lstDevices.OfType(Of Printer).First().iAge)

    Console.ReadKey(True)

End Sub
```

So there 2 lines can be simplified to:

```
'lstDevices.OfType(Of Printer).First().iAge = 10
'Console.WriteLine(lstDevices.OfType(Of Printer).First().iAge)

Printer.iAge = 10
Console.WriteLine(Printer.iAge)
```

If you remove the Shared keyword from iAge, then the code might throw exception if the list if empty. Tim's code is safe because he use FirstOrDefault(), you can check whether firstPrinter is nothing (null) or not, then use the iAge property.